# click event on list view in fragments

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have a list view in fragment and I want to sense the click on list view , so that I can change my layout but my code isn't working.
My xml layout is :

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >


  <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  </ListView>

        </FrameLayout>
```

My code is:

```
ListView lists=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

     lists.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {  
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, 
                                                                 int position, long id) 
           {  
             //  setDetail(position);  
               Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Yea!!! click ho gae called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parentView) {  



           }  
        });
```

But this code is doing nothing,Please help me to sort out, Thanks..

Comment: @gunar yes am populating it by the data from the database.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I assume you're populating the list with some data.

Secondly, you're calling the wrong method as [`setOnItemSelectedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29) is usually called for data selections from the list (the best example is spinner selection). You should be calling [`setOnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) (blind coding):

```
lists.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
           {  
             //  setDetail(position);  
               Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Yea!!! click ho gae called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

        });
```

Comment: then show how you're populating the data. What is the adapter you're using? Is it custom or ArrayAdapter?

Comment: am using array adapter like that :
1-ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Message>) getListAdapter();
2-adapter.add(message);

Comment: ... and you're seeing that data in UI?

Comment: yes all the data can be seen and added in the list correctly,

Comment: I would build a separate list view from an [example that works](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) and then adapt the code to what you currently have. Without revealing more code, it's almost impossible to know what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use onListItemClick method of ListFragment.

So add that code to your `ListFragment` class:

```
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Do what you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this in you code:

```
YOUR_LIST_VIEW.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()     {  
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
       {  

           Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "I was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

U are wrongly implementing your xml layout as it must contain only frame layout in which the default fragment listview must be placed at runtime. If u need any further help or code snippet then reply to me.

Answer (score 0):

1.Modify your adapter code like this.

```
ListView lists=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

 lists.setOnItemSelectedListener(your fragment instance);
```

You don't need to implement onClick handler in adapter.

2.Handle onClick override method in your fragment.

```
     @Override
public boolean onClick(View v) {
    //To Do
}
```